# Creating a server-side part of program

Tags: java, server-side

So I have to create a serverside part of my program know, which is topic I know almost nothing about.

What I need is to send a file to server, which will then send it along. I may also need to get some minor data (couple of ints, a string) from the server.

The thing is that I don't know where to even begin. I tried googling a bit, but I got lost servlets, applets, ports, sockets and whatnots...

Knowing what I have to do, can you tell me which classes should I use? I'll figure out the rest myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make code available through a servlet, callable by a URL, and run it on a tomcat server.

You start out by making a servlet. Create a class that extends `HttpServlet`.

To handle HTTP GET requests, override the doGet method:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
```

To handle HTTP POST requests, override the doPost method:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
```

You can make these methods execute logic, or retrieve data, and expose it as something like `HTML`, `XML` or `JSON`.

To map the servlet to the url, you need a `web.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>nameOfYourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.your.package.ServletImplementationClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>nameOfYourServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/my/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

To deploy this to a tomcat server, you need your web.xml and compiled classes to live inside a WEB-INF folder. Zip the WEB-INF folder into an archive, change the extension of the archive to war, and drop it in your tomcat webapps folder.

I think this is about the quickest way to get server logic running, but your way of implementation depends on what you want to achieve, and what server you want to use etc.

It's probably worth your time looking into servlets a bit more. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) link.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ServerSocket` and `Socket` and related classes. For more on this, check out the [Java Networking Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).